# Undefined local variable or method 'current_job' - Wicked Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the first time I have used the Wicked gem and I keep getting an error within my Wicked controller.

The error is this:

> undefined local variable or method `current_job' for # Did you mean? current_user

The controller:

```
class JobStepsController < ApplicationController
 include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :company_info, :payment

  def show
    @job = current_job
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @job = current_job
    @job.attributes = params[:job]
    render_wizard @job
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])
    if @job.save
      session[:job_id] = @job.id
      redirect_to job_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard
    redirect_to @job, notice: 'Thank you for job posting'
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.5.

I don't fully understand why it doesn't work. If someone would explain that would be awesome also!

If you need any other information just ask.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you don't have `current_job` defined, at least not anywhere available to the controller.

The [Wicked docs](https://github.com/schneems/wicked), say the following:

> If you don't have a current_user then check out how to Build a step-by-step object with Wicked.

It sounds to me like you're using `current_job` for Wicked and its steps, rather than `current_user`, and as such the above applies. The docs suggest following the [steps here](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step).

In a simple sense, you're looking for a job in two actions, both of which require an `id` param. This means you can use the following to assign a job to `@job`:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

(Assuming you have a `Job` model.)

Replace the assignment to `@job` with that code in both the `show` and `update` actions and this should work again.

Comment: Did this help at all @miklki14567?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `show` action `current_job` method is not defined, it needs to be defined either in `JobStepsController` or `ApplicationController`.